# Can a managed website and a virtual machine share the same domain name in Azure?

Tags: azure, ftp, dns, web, virtual-server

I have a website hosted on Azure as a managed site. I need to run a separate FTP server and a custom Windows service on virtual machine, but need them to share the same domain name as the site. So what I'd like to be able to do is have mysite.com port 80 go the website, but mysite.com port 21 etc go the virtual machine and connect with the FTP service. How would I go about setting that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user looks up "mysite.com" they are going to get a single IP address, and there is no way via DNS to return different IP addresses based on the port number you are trying to use.  You have a couple options to achieve this solution:

1. Setup an intermediate routing service that accepts all traffic to mysite.com and then routes the traffic to the appropriate website/VM based on the port number.  This is non-trivial and may incur extra costs (you could build the routing service into the existing VM that is serving FTP to reduce the cost).
2. The easier solution is probably to have a CNAME for www.mysite.com pointing to the website, and a CNAME for ftp.mysite.com pointing to the VM.

Comment: The CNAME answer sounds right - as long as it does not have to be a naked domain name, there's really no reason to provide an A or AAAA record.